# Deduction guide для вложенного шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

```
template<typename>
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    struct B {
        explicit B(T) {}
    };

    B(int) -> B<int>;
};


int main() {
    A<int>::B x{42};
}
```

Почему эта программа компилируется clang ([1](https://godbolt.org/z/tJB0hB)), компилируется с предупреждением msvc ([2](https://godbolt.org/z/AP6ehh)), но не компилируется gcc ([3](https://godbolt.org/z/6NDM3p))? Должна ли она компилироваться в соответствии со стандартом?

Comment: Вопрос выглядит как плохо замаскированная копипаста соответствующего вопроса с enSO, включая такую деталь, как шаблонность внешнего класса. (Для проявления этого бага GCC она не нужна.)

Comment: @AnT всё верно. Большинство моих вопросов основаны на существующих баг-репортах, вопросах с enSO, литературе по языку

Comment: Добавив параметр в конструктор вы несколько исказили вопрос (не обязательно в худшую сторону). Исходный вариант использовал конструктор без параметра именно для того, чтобы исключить влияние неявных deduction guides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это баг/недоделка компилятора gcc.
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79501

У вас шаблон класса `B` имеет конструктор с параметром, что заставляет компилятор генерировать неявный deduction guide для этого шаблона (совпадающий с вашим явным). Тот факт, что компилятор MSVC++ "не понял" вашего явного гайда, но тем не менее смог скомпилировать объявление `x` без явного указания шаблонного аргумента для `B`, говорит о том, что неявный гайд компилятор MSVC++ все таки сгенерировал и использовал вполне успешно.

Comment: Раньше в `clang` тоже был [такой баг](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34520). А что скажете насчёт `msvс`? Пока ничего не нашёл

Comment: @Tocic Да, причем баг в GCC не требовал шаблонности внешнего класса.

Comment: @Tocic Что касается MSVC++: он по-видимому тоже не понимает этого deduction guide (потому и выдает такое предупреждение). Объявление объекта `x` же компилируется засчет *неявного* гайда, сгенерированного компилятором для конструктора с параметром. В оригинальном вопросе на enSO потому и использован конструктор без параметра, чтобы исключить генерацию неявного гайда.